# Why eclipse need JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I was reading some articles about how jvm works, and i tested that if i change the jre from Eclipse(installed JREs), the code will be executed in that jvm. So my question is why the eclipse needs to have JAVA_HOME set in environment variables. Does eclipse use that JRE in any form if i select another in Eclipse(installed JREs)

Comment: Eclipse does **not** require JAVA_HOME to be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does **not** require JAVA_HOME to be set, but as info for you, many MANY tools that you can find over the web use inter under the hood oracle tools, those will never run if your computer has no idea where they are located, JAVA_HOME is just a variable in the enviroment, so you( and the tools you use) can execute things like javac or java without telling every time where those are in the pc
.